# Unable to sync library on client with SSL on, stuck to "Connecting to server"

Tags: nginx, ssl

I had the job to configure SSL on our seafile server, I'm a beginner with linux/certificate.

We have a wildcard certificate from GoDaddy and got to convert crt and key extensions, I configured the `default.conf` to set the appropriate configuration, looking like this :

```
#
# The default server
#


server {

    listen 80;
    server_name ***.*******.com;

}

server {

    listen 12443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/*****.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/certs/*****.key;
    server_name ***.*******.com;

    location / {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:8000;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_script_name;

    fastcgi_param       SERVER_PROTOCOL   $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param       QUERY_STRING          $query_string;
    fastcgi_param       REQUEST_METHOD    $request_method;
    fastcgi_param       CONTENT_TYPE          $content_type;
    fastcgi_param       CONTENT_LENGTH    $content_length;
    fastcgi_param       SERVER_ADDR       $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param       SERVER_PORT       $server_port;
    fastcgi_param       SERVER_NAME       $server_name;
    fastcgi_param       REMOTE_ADDR       $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param       HTTPS             on;
    fastcgi_param       HTTP_SCHEME       https;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/seahub.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/seahub.error.log;
    }
```

The URL in SSL runs just fine and everything seems ok on this side but on workstation client side, there is a sync problem with the library getting stuck  "connecting to server". Version of server is 4.0.2 client version is 4.3.4.

In `seafile.log` I get this when I try to sync library with certificate validation on :

```
[10/20/15 20:12:15] http-tx-mgr.c(653): libcurl failed to GET https://***.******.com:12443/seafhttp/protocol-version: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates.
[10/20/15 20:12:15] clone-mgr.c(812): Transition clone state for 9156de90 from [connect] to [connect].
[10/20/15 20:12:18] clone-mgr.c(812): Transition clone state for 9156de90 from [connect] to [canceled].
```

Sure there is a temporary solution of removing the certificate validation on client advanced options but it would be very nice to get it working.

Am I missing something? Any help would be very appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered for future visitors, since it's a little outdated.

A not ending "Connecting to server" state in Seafile client is usually due to the client not being able to check the certificate. This happens, when you use self signed certificates, but can also happen if your web server OR seafile are not configured to the correct hostname, in which case the check will also fail.

You can configure the client to not verify the certificate in the advanced settings dialogue.